# What does "pointer being freed was not allocated" mean exactly?

Tags: c

I have trouble with a program where im trying to copy a string to a structs string variable in c. After copying the string im trying to free the temporary string variable which is copied to the structs string variable. But when i try to free the string the program turns on me and says that "pointer being freed was not allocated". I don't understand exactly what is going on.

```
char str[]="       ";           //temporary string to copy to structs string
str[3]=s;                       //putting a char s in middle
strcpy(matrix[i-1][j].c, str);  //copying the string
free(str);                      //freeing str that now is useless when copied
```

Comment: It means you're only supposed to call `free` on a pointer you obtained from `malloc`, `realloc` or `calloc`. E.g., `char *str = malloc(10); ... free(str);`. Since you haven't called `malloc`, you shouldn't call `free`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Only pointers returned by calls to `malloc()`, `realloc()` or `calloc()` can be passed to `free()` (dynamically allocated memory on the heap). From section *7.20.3.2 The free function* of C99 standard:

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. **Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the calloc, malloc, or realloc function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc,
>   the behavior is undefined.**

In the posted code, `str` is not dynamically allocated but is allocated on the stack and is automatically released when it goes out of scope and does not need to be `free()`d.

Comment: There may be other functions that return `free`able pointers (`strdup` for example), but for those functions, the docs should specifically say the function returns a pointer "suitable for passing to free()" (or words to that effect).

Comment: @cHao, according the to C standard it is these three functions only. The other functions may be functions such as `strdup()`, which presumably call `malloc()` underneath.

Answer (score 12):

Be careful.  This code shows confusion about two things:

1. The difference between stack and heap memory
2. The operation of `strcpy`

**Point 1**

This has already been answered in a way, but I'll expand a little:

The *heap* is where dynamic memory is given to your process.  When you call `malloc` (and related functions), memory is returned on the heap.  You must `free` this memory when you are done with it.

The *stack* is part of your process's running state.  It is where ordinary variables are stored.  When you call a function, its variables are pushed onto the stack and popped back off automatically when the function exits.  Your `str` variable is an example of something that is on the stack.

**Point 2**

I'd like to know what that `c` member of your matrix array is.  If it is a pointer, then you might be confused about what `strcpy` does.  The function only copies bytes of a string from one part of memory to another.  So the memory has to be available.

If `c` is a `char` array (with sufficient number of elements to hold the string), this is okay.  But if `c` is a pointer, you *must* have allocated memory for it already if you want to use `strcpy`.  There is an alternative function `strdup` which allocates enough memory for a string, copies it, and returns a pointer.  You are responsible for `free`ing that pointer when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 3):

It used `free` without using `malloc`. You can't release memory that hasn't been allocated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't allocate any memory for the string. It simply copies a string from one string to the memory used by another (a string of spaces).

Memory is allocated using functions like `malloc()`, `realloc()`, etc. and then freed with `free()`. Since this memory was not allocated that way, passing the address to `free()` results in the error.

Answer (score 1):

You did not use `malloc()` to allocate space in the heap for `str`. Therefore, `str` is allocated on the stack and cannot be deallocated with `free()`, but will be deallocated when `str` goes out of scope, i.e. after the function containing the declaration returns.